# Support for hibernate validations annotations in Swagger Core V3

Tags: yaml, swagger, jax-rs, hibernate-validator

We're using JEE with Jersey application and I'm trying to generate yaml file from the code (code first approach) using **swagger-maven-plugin** and this [guide](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-maven-plugin/README.md).
The plugin is ignoring **hibernate validations annoations**, and so I found out that need to add **swagger-hibernate-validations.1.6.2** dependency and register the **BeanValidator** in **Application** class:

```
public Map<String, Object> getProperties() 
{
         ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new BeanValidator());
         return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

The thing is that **swagger-hibernate-validations* is for an older version of **swagger core - 1.6.2**, and so I cannot register **BeanValidator** to **ModelConverters** which is of newer version - **swagger core 2.1.2**, which has different packages names.

I didn't find **swagger-hibernate-validations** for the newer swagger-core version, and so my question is how to make the swagger plugin read hibernate validation annotations when using latest swagger plugin version?

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of the plugin - swagger-maven-plugin **2.1.4** - has solved the issue.